# custom-style vs shared-styles in polymer

Tags: css, polymer-1.0

Polymer has support for `<style is="custom-style">` which allows you to define styles that only apply to elements, e.g. the shadow DOM.

Polymer also has support for `<dom-module id="shared-styles">` which allows you to package a set of style declarations that can be imported into an element definition.

Thus the point of both of them seems to be to allow you to style a polymer element. Why would you use one over the other? The use cases overlap substantially, it seems.

Additional confusion: `shared-styles` can be imported into `custom-style`. Why would you do this? Why not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `<dom-module id="my-shared-styles">` declares a reusable style module hat you can import into elements or `<style is="custom-style">` tags.

Use in a custom element

```
<dom-module id="my-element>
  <template>
    <style include="my-shared-styles"></style>
    ...
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

or in the `<style>` tag outside a custom element (for example in `<head>`)

```
<head>
  <style is="custom-style" include="my-shared-styles"></style>
</head>
```

`<style is="custom-style">` is only required when you want to use Polymer CSS features (CSS variables and mixins) in a style element that is not inside a `<dom-module>`. Inside `<dom-module>` just `<style>` is enough.

Comment: Is there any problem that can only be solved with one technique but not the other?

Comment: They are both to support polymer CSS features. The difference is the scope where the styles are applied. CSS in `<style is="custom-style">` can't be applied to content inside an elements template unless there are hooks like CSS variables and mixin applications prepared in the elements styles. `<style>` tags inside a component can be applied to the content of the elements template without limitations.